# Errors running nvidia-settings on fresh kubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia

I have installed fresh  kubuntu 22.04 on my laptop   MSI GP70-2PE (GP702PE-426XUA)   and in Driver
manager I have installed  418 (proprietary) and what I see after OS restarted: https://prnt.sc/_XdxizS0yXGS

But running nvidia-settings
I see some errors in console :

```
(nvidia-settings:2079): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 06:45:14.541: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:2079): CRITICAL **: 06:45:14.543: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. This file
       should have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application profiles will
       continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help
       text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.


** (nvidia-settings:2079): WARNING **: 06:45:14.591: PRIME: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/prime-supported” (No such file or directory)
** Message: 06:45:14.591: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

and opened nvidia-settings does not look properly :  https://prnt.sc/O1tCaE3NnYzJ

What is misconfigured and  how can I fix it ?

```
# sudo lshw -numeric -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 840M] [10DE:1341]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:416]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:34 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

all partitions of my OS has a lot of free space :

```
# df -HT  
Filesystem     Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs    824M  1,8M  822M   1% /run
/dev/sdb2      ext4      53G  8,7G   41G  18% /
tmpfs          tmpfs    4,2G     0  4,2G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs    5,3M  4,1k  5,3M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sdb5      ext4      28G  302M   26G   2% /boot
/dev/sdb7      ext4      30G  3,3G   25G  12% /var
/dev/sdb8      fuseblk  399G  149G  250G  38% /mnt/_work_sdb8
/dev/sda1      fuseblk   65G   58G  7,2G  89% /mnt/Win_sda1
/dev/sda6      fuseblk  237G   95G  143G  40% /mnt/Work_sda6
/dev/sda8      fuseblk  628G  606G   23G  97% /mnt/Media_sda8
tmpfs          tmpfs    824M   74k  824M   1% /run/user/1000

$ uname -a
Linux serge-at-home 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Priorly I used   kubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and did not have such problems...